# Parse JSON in JS like GSON in JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, json, gson, double

I need to sign some JSON data in Java and then send the data and sign to NodeJS.

Take a look at this example.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class SomeClass {
    private double n1 = 0.0;
    private double n2 = 3.2544572232515347E-4;

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String getSha256(String value) {
        try{
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(value.getBytes());
            return bytesToHex(md.digest());
        } catch(Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeClass SC = new SomeClass();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(SC);


        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(jsonString);
        JsonObject data = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

        JsonObject rootObject = new JsonObject();
        rootObject.addProperty("sign", getSha256(jsonString));
        rootObject.add("data", data);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(rootObject));
    }
}
```

After all I get this String `{"sign":"c196a32af925e19897b00f430d9043854ccd5c109d2aee10ec15dfa2bbc060b9","data":{"n1":0.0,"n2":3.2544572232515347E-4}}`

The problem happens when I try to parse JSON in JS and check sign.

```
function checkHash(data){
    return data.key === sha(config.server_key + JSON.stringify(data.data) + config.server_key);
}
```

This function return false because the sign of data in JS is `f5bcb176b734f6a38eae9f0a332a00ae3b798c918ec505bc50baac84b3b1a43a`

And I if I look at JSON in JS it looks like `{"n1":0,"n2":0.00032544572232515347}`
So, there is a problem with double in parsing JSON in JS.

And there are some questions:

1) Maybe there is a way to parse JSON by levels(like GSON, `dataObject.get("data").getAsString()`)? I searched a library but I coudn't find anything.

2) Maybe there is another way to sign JSON data in JAVA and check sign in JS?

I found that I can use custom JSONWriter in GSON, but I think there must be more simple way.

**Update for people who may search this question**

I used `java.security.MessageDigest` to make sha256, and it worked fine until I sent some long data. When I package program with Maven it starts making wrong hashes. Using `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex` solved my problem.

Comment: _"So, there is a problem with double in parsing JSON in JS."_ Yea, you can't "Double parse" JSON.

Comment: This has nothing to do with parsing JSON.  Open a console and copy/paste `console.log(3.2544572232515347E-4);`  It's resolves the value of `3.2544572232515347 / 10^4` and shows `0.00032544572232515347`.  If you want to keep the value in its original state then pass it as a string, not a double.

Comment: That said, if the precision is fixed (always 16) then you can use `data.data.n2.toExponential(16)`

Comment: @Archer Thank you, but data structure can be different,

Comment: Just stop using numbers for keys then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `data.data` is a structure of variables in memory, not a simple stream of bytes you can hash. Depending on whitespace and ordering, there are many, many valid string representations of this data, one of which (presumably) hashes to `c196a32af925e19897b00f430d9043854ccd5c109d2aee10ec15dfa2bbc060b9`, and there is no way for `JSON.stringify` to know which you want. (I can't actually see any salting happening in your Java code though?)

if you want to check the signature, you'll need to either pass the object as

```
{ "data": "{\"value\": 1234}", "sig": "abcd" }
```

then parse it to get a string and a signature, verify they match, and then parse the string to get the data; or else move the signature to a header and check it against the entire JSON payload *before* you parse it. The latter is rather more elegant but may be harder to implement.

Equally of course you can do this out-of-the-box simply by using a TLS connection, but of course that might be tricky depending on your server &c.

Comment: Thank you! I thought about it but it will be a bit strange to send JSON in JSON. But I will use it if there are no any other ways.